# HTML5 Canvas issue with iOS Safari

Tags: ios, html, canvas, safari, mask

I am trying to build a painting application in HTML5.

I have an HTML5 Canvas in a div. This div is masked with an SVG file using -webkit-mask.

On iOS Safari and in iBooks Fixed Layout: When you zoom the page by gesture, the mask suddenly stops working revealing the entire canvas and the contents of the div.

1. There is no problem if the contents of the div is an image. Problem is only with Canvas inside.
2. The problem seemed to happen when the zoom crosses a mark - possibly 50%. I.e, if you have already zoomed over 50% and refresh the page, there is no problem until you zoom out below 50% and vice-versa.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.